# If and range in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, vector

**Question 1 :** What does

```
if test_idx:
        X_test, y_test= X[test_idx,:], y[test_idx]
```

and

```
test_idx=range(105,150)
```

in

```
plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y=y_combined, classifier=ppn, test_idx=range(105,150))
```

do?

**Question 2:** Why `range` should start from 105 to 150. I know that the vector `X_test` has 45 data, but why not put, for example, `range (0,45)` ?(I tried to put that and I know that the samples change, but I don't understand the "why" should I choose such that interval)

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X=iris.data[:,[2,3]]
y=iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1, stratify=y)
sc= StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std=sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std= sc.transform(X_test)

ppn= Perceptron( max_iter=40,eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)

def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier,test_idx=None, resolution = 0.02):
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^','v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() -1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:, 1].min() -1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2= np.meshgrid (np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha= 0.3, cmap = cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(), xx2.max())


    for idx, cl in enumerate (np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter (x=X[y == cl, 0], y= X[y == cl, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[idx], marker= markers [idx], label = cl, edgecolor = 'black')

    if test_idx:
        X_test, y_test= X[test_idx,:], y[test_idx]


        plt.scatter(X_test[:,0], X_test[:,1], c='', edgecolor= 'black', alpha= 0.9, linewidth=1, marker='o', s=100, label='test set' )


X_combined_std= np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))
y_combined=np.hstack((y_train, y_test))
plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y=y_combined, classifier=ppn, test_idx=range(105,150))
plt.xlabel('sepal length [standardized]')
plt.ylabel('petal length [standardized]')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  I

Comment: Are you asking us why you wrote the code the way you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function definition, `test_idx` has a default value of `None`:

```
def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier,test_idx=None, resolution = 0.02):
```

If it is `None`, the following does not get executed, but if you do provide a value (nonzero), then it does the indexing:

```
    if test_idx:
        X_test, y_test= X[test_idx,:], y[test_idx]
```

This calls that function, defining `test_idx` as a `range` object:

```
plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y=y_combined, classifier=ppn, test_idx=range(105,150))
```

If `X_combined_std` or `y_combined` are numpy arrays (or array like objects), then the `test_idx` range selects a 'range' of values; as demonstrated in:

```
In [120]: x = np.arange(10)                                                                                     
In [121]: x[range(3, 6)]                                                                                        
Out[121]: array([3, 4, 5])
```

The choice of `range(105, 150)` versus `range(0,45)` is just a matter of which data points/samples/sets you want to plot.

At the start the `iris` dataset was loaded as `X` and `y`, then split into training and test sets.  `combined` joins them, and this range selects values from the combined arrays.

```
 y_combined=np.hstack((y_train, y_test))
```

Looks like `iris` has 150 samples.  With a `test_size` of .3, 150*.3 is 45.  So in the combined array, the last 45 elements are `test`, the others `training`.  So this (105,150) range plots just the test values. (0,45) would plot a subset of the the training values, which probably isn't meaningful.